# How to fix "You must pass in a non null View" error in android studio

Tags: firebase, android-studio

I'm trying to retrieve an image from Firebase using Glide to a listview. I'm getting the error "You must pass in a non null View".

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.imagetarget);

    img = new Image();
    listView = findViewById(R.id.imagegrid);
    target = findViewById(R.id.target);



    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = database.getReference("Image");
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.getimage, R.id.name,  arrayList);
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                img = ds.getValue(Image.class);
                final String url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/arapp-d03cb.appspot.com/o/bacteria-1-450x285.jpg?alt=media&token=db1e3e3d-f56d-417d-b358-c10ce6f9ae37";
                arrayList.add(img.getName() + "\n"  + img.getDescription() + "\n" + Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url).into(target));



            }
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
```

I expect the image to load into the listview with texts. Is there any other way to do this other than this method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Glide error when loading a recyclerView "You must pass in a non null View"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39451740/glide-error-when-loading-a-recyclerview-you-must-pass-in-a-non-null-view)